# Как присвоить переменной значение из файла txt?

Tags: javascript

Сделал расширения, хочу сделать персональную функцию добавив id пользователей в txt файл, при нажатии кнопки будет использоваться условие(Если найден в текстовом файле id данного человека, то функция выполняется.).

Нашел несколько кодов обращения к файлу txt но все приводят к ошибке:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного
>   источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на
>   http://mysite.ru/file.txt. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

Или как возможно реализовать эту функцию проще?

Comment: Про какие расширения идет речь?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian расширение для google chrome